# Lang's remark on Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

On his book "Introduction to transcendental numbers", page 99-100, Lang wrote
"Finally, we note that Lindemann actually proves something slightly stronger than the algebraic independenceof $e^{\alpha_1},\cdots,e^{\alpha_n}$ if $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. He proved that if $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_m$ are non-zero distinct algebraic numbers, then $e^{\beta_1},\cdots,e^{\beta_m}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. This does not come out of the Siegel method"

I do not understand the latter is stronger than the former. Even, I thought it was the converse. I always thought about this kind of proof. Assume that the values $E(\beta_1),\cdots,E(\beta_m)$ of an $E$-function $E$ are $\overline{\mathbb Q}$-linearly dependant. Then there exists $\gamma_1,\cdots,\gamma_m$ in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ not all zero such that $\gamma_1E(\beta_1)+\cdots+\gamma_mE(\beta_m)=0$. Denote by $G$ the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\gamma_1,\cdots,\gamma_m)/\mathbb Q$. Then $\prod_{\sigma\in G}\left(\sigma(\gamma_1)E(\beta_1)+\cdots+\sigma(\gamma_m)E(\beta_m)\right)=0$. The polynomial $\prod_{\sigma\in G}(\sigma(\gamma_1)X_1+\cdots+\sigma(\gamma_m)X_m)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Q$, is not zero and vanishes at $E(\gamma_1),\cdots,E(\gamma_m)$. It is impossible since the $E(\gamma_i)$ are assumed to be algebraically independant over $\mathbb Q$.

I do not see where is my mistake. Any enlightenment would be welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brevity of notation, if $I = (i_1,\ldots,i_n) \in \mathbf N^n$, write $x^I = x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}$. Write $\boldsymbol \alpha$ for $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, and set $I \cdot \boldsymbol \alpha = i_1\alpha_1 + \ldots + i_n\alpha_n$.

If $e^{\alpha_1},\ldots,e^{\alpha_n}$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbf Q$, then there exists a polynomial
$$f = \sum_{I \in \mathbf N^n} a_I x^I \in \mathbf Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$$
such that $f(e^{\alpha_1},\ldots,e^{\alpha_n}) = 0$. This means that
$$\sum_{I \in \mathbf N^n} a_I e^{I \cdot \boldsymbol \alpha} = 0.$$
By Lindemann's result, this is only possible if there are $I, J \in \mathbf N^n$ with $I \neq J$ such that $a_I, a_J \neq 0$ and
$$i_1\alpha_1 + \ldots + i_n \alpha_n = j_1\alpha_1 + \ldots + j_n \alpha_n.$$
In particular the $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbf Q$.

What's different in your argument is that you replaced $\mathbf Q$-linear dependence by $\bar{\mathbf Q}$-linear dependence.

Comment: Thank you. I see my problem now.